# Edit windows service to log on as specific user using a batch script

Tags: windows-7, batch, services, windows-services

I have several programs that are installed as a service.

By default, after installation, the service runs as Local System Account.

I can change it through services.msc, service properties to the desired account.
Is there a way to do the above using a script ?

Comment: Found the solution, hope it will hope others.


From command line:

sc \\server config ServiceName obj= Domain\user password= pass

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer, so that you can accept it and close the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
sc \\server config ServiceName obj= Domain\user password= pass
```

hope it helps.